# How to test if linked list nodes were deleted in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I was testing a recursive function that frees the memory of a linked list. I attempted to print the list's contents after deleting it to ensure that it had been deleted, but it doesn't seem to be possible to test if a node has been deleted since the pointer still exists. I get the same errors while using a simpler function to delete the list as well. Unless I'm making a mistake somewhere my question is:

Is there a way to test for deleted nodes?

My delete function:

```
template <typename node>
void deleteList(node root) {
    if (!root) {
        return;
    }

    deleteList(root->next);
    delete root;
}
```

My print list function:

```
template <typename node>
void printList(node root) {
    node current = NULL;
    if (root) {
        current = root;
        cout << "if (root) == true\n";
        cout << "root is: " << root << "\n";
    }

    while (current) {
        cout << current->in << "\n";
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

If I call printList(node) after I've called deleteList(node), printList evaluates `if (root)` to true as well as `while (current)`, so `cout << current->in` ends up causing a segmentation fault.

Comment: Why do you call `printList(node)` after calling `deleteList(node)` in the first place?

Comment: @Peter To test if the list was correctly deleted perhaps?

Comment: I understand that's the expectation.    I'm asking why that is the expectation in the first place.    It's akin to attempting to access a variable after it has passed out of scope.   The most general solution is not to try to test for such cases - it is to prevent them happening in the first place BY DESIGN.

Comment: That said, although I think the premise of the question is fundamentally flawed, I've marked your answer up as it does provide a solution to the question as asked.

Comment: @Peter yes it was purely for testing. I was originally under the impression that a deleted pointer would return false in an if statement but quickly learned that the pointer is still valid but points to garbage. That lead me to wonder how to prevent that from happening and have now discovered the use of nullptr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delete` doesn't set the pointer to `nullptr`, you have to do that manually:

```
template <typename node>
void deleteList(node& root) {
                 // ^
    if (!root) {
        return;
    }

    deleteList(root->next);
    delete root;
    root = nullptr; // <<<<<<<<<<<
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `node& root` when I'm already passing it a pointer? (I see that it only works correctly when done this way, but I don't understand why)

Comment: Without the `&`, the pointer `root` is passed by value.   While it is possible to change things that `root` points at, passing `root` by value means the function receives a copy of the value passed by the caller, and assignments (like `root = nullptr`) only change the local copy.  The purpose of `node & root` in the parameter list is therefore to make the effect of the assignment `root = nullptr` visible to the caller.

Comment: I see now. I was so accustomed to the fact that pointers as parameters can directly affect their contents that it didn't occur to me that the pointer itself was local. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

When you free memory it is good practice to set the pointer to it to null (`nullptr` in modern C++). This makes it easier to test if that memory is freed later. It is part of defensive programming.

This will cause your `(!root)` check to fail on freed memory. This is a practice you should follow for all dynamically allocated memory so that you do not try and use an invalid pointer. Much better to crash due to a null pointer than to have code that seems to work but is actually corrupted.